# How To Prevent Duplicates In Object ArrayList in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

```
var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var secondArray = [1,2,3,7,8,9,0]

for item in secondArray {
//    some thing that i can avoid duplicate
    firstArray.append(item)
}
print(firstArray)
//end result should be firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

i want to prevent firstArray to append duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var secondArray = [1,2,3,7,8,9,0]
let _ = secondArray.map{
     if !(firstArray.contains($0)){
          firstArray.append($0)
     }
}

print(firstArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var secondArray = [1,2,3,7,8,9,0]

firstArray = NSOrderedSet(array: firstArray + secondArray).array as! [Int]
print(firstArray)
```